# actionListener and ajax event misbehaving in my code 1st click failed but 2nd click working as expected

Tags: java, ajax, icefaces

**Form Labels and onclick behaviour!**
`src="/WEB-INF/includes/fragment/edm/linkedValuePair.xhtml"`

````
                   <h:commandLink actionListener="#{bean[listener]}">
                     <f:ajax event="action" execute="@this" render="@all"/>
                     <h:outputText value="#{label}" styleClass="ui-input-label"/>
                   </h:commandLink>
                   <h:commandLink actionListener="#{bean[listener]}">
                     <f:ajax event="action" execute="@this" render="@all"/>
                     <h:outputText value="#{value}"/>
                   </h:commandLink> 
                 </h:panelGrid>```
**Above code is the issue which is misbehaving !**
          ``` <ace:panel header="Media" styleClass="lp" id="mediaPanel">
                     <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="w100">
                       <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/fragment/edm/linkedValuePair.xhtml">
                         <ui:param name="bean" value="#{frontPage}"/>
                         <ui:param name="listener" value="manageLogos"/>**Bean method !**
                         <ui:param name="label" value="Logos"/>
                         <ui:param name="value" value=""/>
                       </ui:include>
                       <hr class="hrb"/>          
                       <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/fragment/edm/linkedValuePair.xhtml">
                         <ui:param name="bean" value="#{frontPage}"/>
                         <ui:param name="listener" value="manageImages"/>**Bean method !**
                         <ui:param name="label" value="Images"/>
                         <ui:param name="value" value=""/>
                       </ui:include>
                       <hr class="hrb"/>    
                       <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/fragment/edm/linkedValuePair.xhtml">
                         <ui:param name="bean" value="#{frontPage}"/>
                         <ui:param name="listener" value="managePdfs"/>**Bean method !**
                         <ui:param name="label" value="Catalogues / Menus"/>
                         <ui:param name="value" value=""/>
                       </ui:include>
                       <hr class="hrb"/>  
                       <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/fragment/edm/linkedValuePair.xhtml">
                         <ui:param name="bean" value="#{frontPage}"/>
                         <ui:param name="listener" value="manageVideos"/>**Bean method !**
                         <ui:param name="label" value="Videos"/>
                         <ui:param name="value" value=""/>
                       </ui:include>
                       <hr class="hrb"/>  
                       <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/fragment/edm/linkedValuePair.xhtml">
                         <ui:param name="bean" value="#{frontPage}"/>
                         <ui:param name="listener" value="manageGalleries"/>**Bean method !**
                         <ui:param name="label" value="Galleries"/>
                         <ui:param name="value" value=""/>
                       </ui:include>
                     </h:panelGrid>
                   </ace:panel>```
**when I click on logos its directing to managepdfs where it supposed to direct to managelogos listner** **please advise ! appreciate your help !**
````

Comment: when I click on label logos it's listener pointing to managepdfs bean method where it supposed to direct to managelogos listener,please advise whats wrong here! Really appreciate your help !

Comment: There is 5 labels on the form which are  Logos, Images, pdfs, Videos, Galleries in sequence. so 1st click on Logos label directing to pdfs and first click on Images directing to videos.. like 1 goes to 3 and 2 goes to 4 and 3 goes to 3.